# How to run initial Android setup after skipping it?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nvidia-shield, setup-wizard

So, as part of rooting my Nvidia Shield Tablet K1, I wanted to set some things up before running the initial setup, things like configuring the adoptive storage, that seemed to make sense before downloading all my old apps. I was able to skip the setup and do what I needed but then couldn't find a way to run the setup after the fact. Can I force the device to run the setup again?

Comment: Hmm. The linked question isn't quite the same question, but the question itself gives the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Some Googling later, I found that you can send this command to your device:

> adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n  com.google.android.setupwizard/.SetupWizardTestActivity

and it will rerun the setup. In my particular case it came up with an error several times to the point I was a bit panicked and decided to try rebooting. Once I rebooted, the error came up again but I clicked through it and then it said "Just a sec" for quite a while but eventually got on with the normal setup.